# Как вывести ошибку выполнения JavaScript кода на экран?

Tags: javascript, консоль, cordova

Не могу отладить js-приложение на cordova. Пытаюсь добраться до нативных функций телефона (в данном случае до геолокации). Написал несколько функций и в каждой вставил примерно следующее `alert('выполняется функция *название*');` По логике кода должны выполниться все функции, но выполняется только одна (судя по алертам). Если запустить приложение в браузере, то ошибка выводится в консоль, но в данном случае тестировать надо именно в телефоне или эмуляторе, в которых нет консоли. Есть ли возможность вывести ошибку js-кода на экран?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать конструкцию:

```
try {
  //тут код, который хотите отладить
} catch (err) {
  var errorElem = document.getElementById('error-block-id');
  errorElem.innerHTML = "name: " + err.name + "message" + err.message;
}
```

где #error-block-id - это какой-нибудь dom-элемент, куда вы хотите выносить текст и название ошибки.

Comment: отлично. спасибо.

Comment: @AlMr Если ответ помог решить поставленную задачу - отметьте его как верный.

Answer (score 0):

Позволю себе не согласится с тем, что у телефона нет консоли. Cordova dev сборок прекрасно пишет все в лог андроида.

`adb logcat | grep cordova` 

Или что-то вроде прекрасно показывает только её логи. 

`adb logcat` 

 общий лог.